# Displaying only MM:SS in SQL Server 2012 Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues getting SQL Server manager to display the track length of a song correctly, I am currently using the data type time(7) however it is displaying the track length of 04:09 as 00:04:09.0000000.  What data type should I be using?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need precision beyond seconds and that length in general is short cannot you just user a integer to account the seconds? At the UI you can easily convert that for minutes:seconds

Comment: There is a world of difference between the data-type and how it displays as a string.  Your values are *not* stored in the data-base as `00:04:09.0000000` it only looks that way when converted to a string in order to display on a screen *(even if you're not using `CONVERT` there is an **implicit** `CONVERT`)*.  If you must convert the value in the SQL (it should normally be done in the presentation layer), you can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), yourField, 8)` then you get the format `'hh:mi:ss'`, though there *are* other formats you could choose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Do not confuse `Time` and `Duration`. What you are storing is duration, and you should be using a numeric data type for this. Although unlikely, how would you store a song that lasted over 24 hours? As has been said, you can do any required formatting in the UI.

Comment: The table is going to be displayed in a ASP.net website I am working on.  I am new to both SQL and ASP.net so I assume from what you guys are saying is that I should store the duration of the song as time in SQL then reformat it later in the actual site?

Answer (score 2):

THis is not a question of data type than of using the right tool.

What do oyu care how things are formatted in management studio - you will run your own application and can format things there as you want. Management Studio is a general purpose system.

That said, is there a reason to even sture sub-second parts? YOu explicitly ask for a time(7) which has a resolution of 0.0000001 seconds. Maybe you shoudl read on the data types and then ask for the proper time in your table definition?

[MSDN Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)
 has a list of all data types and that leads for time to

[Another link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

I assume you are cabable of reading that part and the nadjusting your table yourself. Little hint - to store only seconds, you want a time(0).